# MonoTouch.Dialog: Arabic Elements

Tags: internationalization, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, right-to-left

Is there a way to have the text in a `StyledStringElement` be RTL so that Arabic and Farsi and Hebrew can render correctly?

I create an StyledStringElement:

```
var eBahai = new StyledStringElement ("بهائی");
```

When rendered it is left aligned, not right aligned.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly (I'm not used to RTL). It this specific to `StyledStringElement` or does other elements, like `StringElement`, behave in the same way ? (my own test seems to indicate this). Also could you edit your question to include an example (code and pictures of what's expected and what's being showed) ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StyledStringElement elm = new StyledStringElement("your caption");
elm.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
```

if I understood you right, that's should work for you